# Are there any risks to setting a stored procedure's Deadlock_Priority to high?

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

I have a very important scheduled stored procedure that halfway through running yesterday was chosen as the deadlock victim. I'm new to the concept of deadlock victims, and have found a few sites describing how they work. On Stack Overflow, there are questions around the issue, but I can't see any detailing the risks, if there are any at all.

I want to make sure that this never happens again, and the procedure is given priority to run over anything else.

I have read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-deadlock-priority-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 that I can set this in the stored procedure by stating `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH` at the start of it.

As quoted in the above site:

> LOW maps to -5, NORMAL to 0, and HIGH to 5

Which means that it will take priority over any other processes that are less than 5. We don't have this stated anywhere else, and no other procedures are set to any numeric value.

So if I set my procedure to `HIGH`, is this a fairly safe thing to do, i.e. it won't cause internal server functions to cease etc.?

Comment: Off-topic - belongs on dba. Short answer: yes, it is safe. Longer answer: far, FAR better to find the source of the deadlock and fix it (if possible) or address the entire scenario from a position of knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm using the SQL Server Profiler to find the culprit, which has been very helpful so far. I agree that eliminating the source of the deadlock is the better solution. It is more of a precaution against other ad-hoc queries interfering in the future.